# Passing function as parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, parameters, porting

Have to port a little piece of code from JavaScript to JAVA:

```
var N = 3;
var w = 8, h = 8;

var matrix = [ 

               [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
               [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

             ];

//[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
console.log(complexFunction(2, 1));

//first function
function simpleFunction(f_) {

    var out = new Array(N * N);

    for (var y = 0; y < N; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < N; x++) {

        out[x + y * N] = f_(x, y);

        }
    }

    return out;

};

//second function     
function complexFunction(x_, y_) {

    return simpleFunction(function (dx, dy) { return matrix[(x + dx) % w][(y + dy) % h]; });

};
```

Have experimented with Callable without any success. 
Ideally, the ported result should have the same structure as JavaScript source.

Comment: You need to post your Java code and explain what you're trying to do, and where you're having problems.  The Javascript code is not really important to the question *"How to pass a function as a reference in Java"*

Comment: If you are using Java 8 or higher, you can use the [functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html).

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Don't expect us to do that translation work for you. Start yourself, and then, when you are stuck, ask about help with that.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I have to use Java 7, which doesn't have lambdas,
so had to make everything as simple as possible:

```
Integer[] complexFunction(int dx_, int dy_){

     Integer[] out = new Integer[N * N];

     for (Integer y = 0; y < N; y++) {
        for (Integer x = 0; x < N; x++) {

          out[x + y * N] = matrix[(x + dx_) % w][(y + dy_) % h];

        }
     }
     return out; 

}
```

Comment: This answer is of no use to anyone but you. This question should just be deleted.